# Disable/Enable input for each item from a loop VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to enable/disable each input from a loop. The problem is that my method it works just after refresh. After I modify something in code and save, then the input works.

```html
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in customer_names" :key="item.id">
        <td>
            <input :disabled="!item.disabled"
                v-model="item.name"
                type="text" 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <div class="edit_mode"
        :class="{'display-none':!item.disabled}">
        <i class="fa fa-save" @click="disableInput(index)" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="edit_mode"
        :class="{'display-none':item.disabled}">
        <i class="fa fa-edit" @click="enableInput(index)" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
```

```js
    props:['customer_names'],
    data(){
        return{
            disabled: [],
        }
    }
    enableInput(index){
        console.log('enableInput',this.customer_names[index].disabled);
        this.customer_names[index].disabled = false;
    },
    disableInput(index){
        console.log('disabeInput',this.customer_names[index].disabled);
        this.customer_names[index].disabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Are `item` and `index` accessible on those two `div`s with class `edit_mode`? I mean, you defined them as `v-for` variables in the `tr`.

Comment: Yes, are accessible. My method works just after reflesh, I take a look now on trigger update methods.

Comment: Update on my earlier comment - as @mrmowji said, this shouldn't work but it works, I believe, because you don't have closing tag on `input` element. Also, "it works after refresh" means you have some AJAX call that stores the values?

Comment: @Beusebiu Would you please provide an HTML page which represent your issue? That way anyone can test your code easier. Github, JSFiddle, and other online services are fine.

Comment: @Beusebiu, it seems that you excluded code from your vue component which makes it hard to understand but I would say that when I experience this issue its because the data had not yet been received so maybe try doing a `v-if="customer_names"` on your `v-for="(item, index) in customer_names"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't fully understand your problem. I deduced that you might want to enable or disable the text fields that you create from the data provided. If this is still not what you meant, correct your question by pasting more source code, and explain your problem in more detail.

```js
Vue.component("custom", {
  template: "#custom-template",
  props: ["customer_names"],
  methods: {
    enableInput(item) {
      item.disabled = false;
    },
    disableInput(item) {
      item.disabled = true;
    },
    toggleInput(item) {
      item.disabled = !item.disabled;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { name: "fus", disabled: false },
        { name: "ro", disabled: false },
        { name: "dah", disabled: true }
      ]
    };
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <custom :customer_names="items" />
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="custom-template">
  <table cellpadding=5>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Version 1</th>
      <th>Version 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in customer_names" :key="item.id">
      <td>
        <input :disabled="item.disabled" v-model="item.name" type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button @click="item.disabled = false">E</button>
        <button @click="item.disabled = true">D</button>
        <button @click="item.disabled = !item.disabled">T</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button @click="enableInput(item)">E</button>
        <button @click="disableInput(item)">D</button>
        <button @click="toggleInput(item)">T</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</script>
```